# ASP.NET application initially fails with: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I apologize if I missed any details in this post, it's a bit bewildering and seems to be more of a bug in the OS than anything else.

We have an ASP.NET web application running on Windows Server 2019. The application attempts to make a web connection to another hosted application. We are trying to force it to use TLS1.2. When we do, the initial connection request ALWAYS fails after restarting IIS and then works fine from that point on.

I've installed Wireshark and can confirm that there is NO TCP connection attempt made on the wire whatsoever. Instead, we get an error from the application that the connection was forcibly closed.

> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport
>   connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote
>   host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection
>   was forcibly closed by the remote host    at
>   System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset,
>   Int32 size)

The ASP.NET application is using .NET 4.5.2. The simplified code looks like so:

```
try {
    HttpWebRequest hwrequest = (HttpWebRequest) System.Net.WebRequest.Create("https://api.domain.com/");
    hwrequest.Accept = "*/*";
    hwrequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
    hwrequest.UserAgent = "http_requester/0.1";
    hwrequest.Timeout = 900000;
    hwrequest.Method = "POST";
    hwrequest.KeepAlive = false;
    hwrequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8";

    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(delegate {
        return true;
    });
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

    System.Text.ASCIIEncoding encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
    byte[] postByteArray = encoding.GetBytes(postData);
    hwrequest.ContentLength = postByteArray.Length;
    System.IO.Stream postStream = hwrequest.GetRequestStream();
    postStream.Write(postByteArray, 0, postByteArray.Length);
    postStream.Close();

    System.Net.HttpWebResponse hwresponse = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse) hwrequest.GetResponse();
    if (hwresponse.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK) {
        System.IO.Stream responseStream = hwresponse.GetResponseStream();
        System.IO.StreamReader myStreamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(responseStream);
        responseData = myStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
    }
    hwresponse.Close();
}
catch(Exception e) {
    Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    responseData = "An error occurred: " + e.Message;
}
```

If we refresh the page, the connection attempt succeeds. But the initial request fails. **If we comment out the line `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;` then there is no problem, but the application uses TLSv1.**

Is there something that you can think of that would cause the initial connection attempt to fail and then all subsequent requests to work until IIS is restarted? Seems like some type of bug in the OS rather than a coding issue.

This is a fully patched Windows Server 2019 almost fresh out of the box on Amazon AWS. There is no security software or extra things installed on it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this generally means that the remote side closed the connection (usually by sending a TCP/IP RST packet). If you're working with a third-party application, the likely causes are:

- You are sending malformed data to the application
- The network link between the client and server is going down for some
  reason
- You have triggered a bug in the third-party application that caused
  it to crash
- The third-party application has exhausted system resources

It's likely that the first case is what's happening.

But You can fire up [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to see exactly what is happening on the wire to narrow down the problem. Without more specific information, it's unlikely that anyone here can really help you much.

Another way is Using TLS 1.2 might solved this error.

You can force your application using TLS 1.2 with this (make sure to execute it before calling your service):

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
```

**Another solution :**

Enable strong cryptography in your local machine or server in order to use TLS1.2 because by default it is disabled so only TLS1.0 is used.
To enable strong cryptography , execute these commande in PowerShell with admin privileges :

Comment: I've done all of this. With the exception of not stating that I also tweaked the registry to enable strong cryptography, I've already indicated that I am 100% certain that there is NO request leaving the server. Wireshark shows no connection is being made from the local server. Therefore, regardless of what the error says, the problem is the server and not the remote host which doesn't even get a connection attempt.

Comment: Maybe this caused by leaving a connection open for too long (accidentally). You probably should refactor your code so that the job is kicked off by the service, and the service method terminates. At that point, you can either have the remote host contact your machhine via WCF (or TCP) when the job is done, and then your app can retrieve the data.